# AWS EC2 Instance not getting the credentials from InstanceProfile

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an EC2 instance which is mapped with InstanceProfile. But the aws cli does not work for me, and asks to configure credentials.

```
$ aws configure list
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
region           ap-southeast-2              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

Should the ec2 instance get the credentials automatically using the Instance profile ? How can I make it work ?

**My Expectation:**

```
  aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
    access_key     ****************4G         iam-role
    secret_key     ****************83         iam-role
    region           ap-southeast-2              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

Comment: Yes it should. Are you certein that the instance has the role attached? Also you can check with `aws sts get-caller-identity` .

Comment: @Marcin # aws sts get-caller-identity
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure". . I cant run any aws cli comamnds as credentials are not available. Is there a way I can force to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the proxy used by my system.

The Best way to check is below command:

```
GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam; echo
```

Try setting the correct proxy or add 169.254.169.254 to NO_PROXY and see whether you get a valid output for the above command.

Comment: Giving this answer an up, this gave me a clue on why our instance couldn't find any roles. Our proxy was on.

Answer (score -1):

The general and correct workflow to use aws cli with ec2 instance `is to not configure your keys on instance ever`( for security reasons you don't want your keys to be on a instance which you don't own) just configure the **default region** using `AWS configure` that's it.

From the sole create a role for ec2 instance which gives access to any of the resource **for eg permission to read s3 buckets** and attach that role to your ec2 instance

To attach a role to your instance:-
-> right-click on your instance
-> attach I am the role
-> search for the role and that's it

Comment: I have got a role(InstanceProfile) attached already. The same role works well in a different ec2. Both ec2 insatnces have almost the same config.

Comment: check your role permissions once